# Informatica export objects

Tags: unix, informatica

I am exporting objects from informatica repository using unix script.

I used following command to export the mapping.

```
  pmrep objectexport -n <m_test_mapping> -o mapping -f <folder_name> -u   <export_path>
```

it is working fine.
But when I tried to export one expression transformation in mapping it's giving error as the 'The transformation object doesn't exist'
To export expression I used following command,

```
 pmrep objectexport -n <expression_name> -o transformation -t expression -f <folder_name> -m -s -b -r -u <export_path>
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can export a reusable expression, that is a separate, independent object within the Repository. I'm afraid you can't export one transformation from within a mapping.
If that is what you need, just export the whole mapping, edit it, and get the required transformation.